# Date not change while repalce "." to "/"

Tags: excel, vba

I'am trying to replace `.` to `/` on selection but after replace some cell not change. I have to change it mannual by click enter. Please suggest it via VBA. for change. I also try to calculate and numberformat but both are not working

[image]

```
Sub Reverse_Cheque()
    Dim ChequeDate As String, i As Long
    i = 2
    'Debug.Print ChequeDate.Address
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("L:L").Insert
    Range("L1").Value = "expire date"
    
    Do Until Range("k" & i).Value = ""
        ChequeDate = Range("K" & i).Value
        Range("k" & i).Value = Replace(Range("k" & i).Value, ".", "/")
        Range("k" & i).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy"
        'Range("L" & i).Value = Range("k" & i).Value + 89
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any periods (.) in your image? Only hyphens (-)

Comment: Your question is a [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask X but your problem is Y. Please describe what your actual problem is. If it is about converting date formats this can brobably not be solved with replace. Please read [mcve] and show example input and desired output data including a despription of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> Range("k" & i).Value = Replace(Range("k" & i).Value, ".", "/")
>
> Range("k" & i).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyy"

This is not the right way to do it. This will only work if the previous number format is "General". This is an example to replicate the above issue. The below will not work.

```
[A1].NumberFormat = "@"
[A1].Value = #1/1/2021#
[A1].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

For the above to work, you will have to press <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The below will work without <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
[A1].NumberFormat = "General"
[A1].Value = #1/1/2021#
[A1].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

And hence it is always advisable to change the number format first before inputing new data.

Also you do not need a loop. You can use `.Replace` to replace all `.` in one go. Here is an example. Change it to suit your needs.

```
With Columns("K")
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End With
```

Comment: i m trying to use both method same issue found, while on with columns they are showing error for  FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2 :varriable not found)

Comment: If you use just `.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart` then what happens?